# Error adding array to MongoDB / Mongoose collection

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, knockout.js, mongoose

I am trying to add an array to a Mongo document, and I'm getting the error `"Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object],[object Object]" at path "vendors""`

Here is my model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    vendors: {
      type: [String]
    },
    description: {
      type: String
    }
  }
};
```

Here is my code to create:

```
var vendors = ko.observableArray(['foo','bar']);
var desc = ko.observable('yadda yadda yadda');
var dto = {
    data: {
      vendors: vendors(),
      description: description()
    }
};
DataService.quoteRequest.create(dto);
```

Comment: what does your custom vendors code look like?

Comment: That was a typo, should have been vendors. I fixed it.

Comment: Regardless of the knockout, if I pass a plain array in the DTO I get the same error.

Comment: where are you definining your schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Musical Shore,

I'm not familiar with knockout.js, but in regards to Mongoose it doesn't look like you are defining your [`Schema`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and [`Model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html). You would need to do the following:

**Define Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var attributesSchema = new Schema({
  vendors: [String],
  description: String
});
```

**Create a Model**

```
var Attributes = mongoose.model('Attribute',attributesSchema);
```

**Create and Save a Document**

```
//create an attribute document
var attribute = new Attributes(
   { 
     vendors: vendorsArray,
     description: desc
    }
 );

attribute.save(function(err){
if(!err) console.log('Success');
}
```